# Post multiple Objects with RestKit (as JSON-Array)

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit, restkit-0.20

I'm trying to send multiple objects as an array to a Server with `RestKit`. Unfortunately I'm not able to do so.
Following my pretty simple objects as well as the mapping for RestKit:

#### Example Objects

```
@interface MyExampleObject : NSObject

@property NSString *key;
@property NSString *value;

@end
```

#### Array-Object holding multiple of MyExampleObject

```
@interface MyArray : NSObject

@property NSArray *array;

@end
```

#### Mapping

```
RKObjectMapping *mappingObject = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[MyExampleObject class]];
[mappingObject addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                              @"key" : @"key",
                                              @"value" : @"value"
                                              }];

RKObjectMapping *mappingArray = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[MyArray class]];
[mappingArray addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"dummy" toKeyPath:@"array" mappingObject]];
```

If I do it this way I’ll get the following result:

```
{
  "dummy" : [
    {
      "key" : "MyKey1",
      "value" : "MyValue1"
    },
    {
      "key" : "MyKey2",
      "value" : "MyValue2"
    }
  ]
}
```

But I want only the array without a „key“. Like this:

```
[
    {
      "key" : "MyKey1",
      "value" : "MyValue1"
    },
    {
      "key" : "MyKey2",
      "value" : "MyValue2"
    }
]
```

It seemed obvious for me to change the `relationshipMappingFromKeyPath` to `nil`. But this didn't worked (got a `setObjectForKey: key cannot be nil` error).

What do I have to do to send multiple `MyExampleObjects` to my Server as a JSON-Array?

### Solution:

As [Wain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1988185/wain) suggested I've removed my "Top-Mapping". Following the final mapping:

```
RKObjectMapping *mappingObject = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[MyExampleObject class]];
[mappingObject addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                              @"key" : @"key",
                                              @"value" : @"value"
                                              }];
```

And when I post the stuff to my Server I just do something like this:

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:myExampleObject1, myExampleObject2, nil];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:array path:@"/myPath/" parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
...
}
```

Comment: Try to paste real code, or at least edit it all so class and variable names match...

Comment: thanks for posting updated solution! came with the same issue

Comment: @Wain can you give me example how to PUT object looking like first json here. I dont want to map response. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just get rid of the `MyArray` object and the associated mapping and directly pass the `NSArray` of `MyExampleObject`s to the post method. RestKit will understand that it's an array of objects to map and do the right thing.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. You were absolutely right. Thanks a lot!